# Test to check if draws came from uniform distribution

Tags: clustering, confidence-interval

I perform clustering and afterwards I want to analyze the clusters to see what are the chances that the data came from a discrete uniform distribution. For example, my clustering might return three clusters each with 100, 110, and 10 data points assigned to each cluster respectively. I want some way to say that the cluster with 10 assigned to it is most likely a mistake since I know the data is equally likely. I think multinomial distribution may be the right direction be am unsure.

Is there some way to say "I'm 90% certain that this clustering came from a discrete uniform distribution of size 2"?

Answer (score 0):

Without a whole lot more information and some assumptions, the answer is "no, there is no such test". Even with more information and some assumptions, the answer might still be the same.

The only way I can think of to test this would be some sort of permutation test. But that would require specifying a lot of things about the underlying population, including the covariance matrix among all the variables being used in the clustering and the means of each variable in each cluster and so on.

But I think there's a more fundamental issue here. You say you want to be able to say:

> "I'm 90% certain that this clustering came from a discrete uniform
>   distribution of size 2"

Even with a permutation test, I think the question you would answer is not:

"How certain am I that these data came from this distribution?" but "If the data come fro this distribution, how likely are these data?"  and these two are not the same and might not even be close.

Why assume that they come from a discrete distribution at all?

If you want to decide on two clusters vs. three, my inclination would be to see how useful each solution is. Maybe those 10 observations are really different than the rest. Or maybe they are not that different, but are different in interesting ways.